# Spark unable to connect to Ignite using JDBC thin driver

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, ignite

I'm working with Java 8, Spark 2.1.1, Ignite 2.5 and BoneCP 0.8.0

Maven pom.xml looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-tester</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kafka.version>0.10.1.2.6.2.0-205</kafka.version>
        <spark.version>2.1.1.2.6.2.0-205</spark.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                    <mainClass>spark.IgniteTester</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My project compiles to a 'fat' jar which contains all of it's dependencies but when running the next code on the Spark cluster:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver").newInstance();
        BoneCPConfig config = new BoneCPConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:ignite:thin://myhost:10840;user=myusername;password=mypassword");
        pool = new BoneCP(config);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("could not load Ignite driver", e);
        return;
    }
}
```

Results the following exception:

```
ERROR IgniteTester: could not load Ignite driver
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:ignite:thin://myhost:10840;user=myusername;password=mypassword, username = null. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ignite:thin://myhost:10840;user=myusername;password=mypassword
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:361)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
        at spark.IgniteTester.main(IgniteTester.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:751)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolUtil.generateSQLException(PoolUtil.java:192)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:422)
        at spark.IgniteTester.main(IgniteTester.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:751)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ignite:thin://myhost:10840;user=myusername;password=mypassword
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:361)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
        ... 10 more
```

Submit script looks like this:

```
spark-submit \
--class spark.IgniteTester \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode master \
--driver-memory 1g \
--executor-cores 1 \
--num-executors  1 \
--executor-memory 1664mb \
ignite-tester.jar
```

When working with a 'local' Spark instance it connects to the Ignite using the think JDBC driver.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please include the build definition.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the pom.xml structure to the original post.

Comment: What happens if you submit the related ignite-jar file within the spark-submit command with the --jar param?

Comment: Same exception with the same trace

Comment: Does it work if you use the JDBC driver directly rather than use BoneCP? Also curious why not use Ignite's built-in Spark support?

Comment: @StephenDarlington Amazingly it works (!) with direct access using - Class.forName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver"); DriverManager.getConnection(...);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who ever gets here eventually - what worked for me was the suggestion above to drop BoneCP as the DB connection pool and use single DB connection:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite:thin://myhost:10840;user=myusername;password=mypassword");
ResultSet rs = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE").executeQuery());
```

if you think about it a bit, it make perfect sense to use only single DB connection, according to my understanding - Spark runs the code in a 'single' thread model anyway so there is no real gain in having more than single connection anyway.
Hope this helps.